# Clear mainPanel Area in Shiny to display something else

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I make a little program in Shiny, bud divided in 5 parts (5 tabs in the sidebar).
But, when I display the firsts plots, and after i display the second, the second is under the first.

I would like to erase the panel to put the new plot correctly in the page.
Here is what I have in the main panel actually.

If i click the button B1 (conditional), the first little program appears. But, if i want to output cPlot1 it appears after gPlotsX.

```
  conditionalPanel(
condition = "input.B1",
column(6,
plotOutput("gPlot1", click = "plot_clickA1"),
verbatimTextOutput("infoA1"),
plotOutput("gPlot3", click = "plot_clickA3"),
verbatimTextOutput("infoA3")),


column(6,
plotOutput("gPlot2", click = "plot_clickA2"),
verbatimTextOutput("infoA2"),
plotOutput("gPlot4", click = "plot_clickA4"),
verbatimTextOutput("infoA4"))),

plotOutput("cPlot1",width = "100%", height = "800px"),
```

How can i do to erase the first part if i want to display the second ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. This is how I imagine your problem and I hope it helps - if not then please provide minimal reproducible example :)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(title = "Panel 1",
                 br(),
                 h4("some content"),
                 checkboxInput(inputId = "B1", label = "Button 1", value = FALSE)
        ),
        tabPanel(title = "Panel 2",
                 br(),
                 h4("some content"),
                 checkboxInput(inputId = "B2", label = "Button 2", value = FALSE)
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.B1", 
                       h4("some content"),
                       h1("Button1 is active")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.B2", 
                       h4("another content"),
                       h1("Button2 is active")
      )
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output, session) {

  observe({ 
    # if the first button is checked - uncheck the second button
    if (input$B1) updateCheckboxInput(session, inputId = "B2", value = FALSE)
  })

  observe({ 
    # if the second button is checked - uncheck the first button
    if (input$B2) updateCheckboxInput(session, inputId = "B1", value = FALSE)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I have an error :
`ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer`

What I want is just clear all the main panel tu put the new plot(s)
In fact, if i launch the options to add a new plot (plot 2), He gets below but not above.
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/35/1440797854-c1.png
As you can see the second graph is under the first. (left)
I just want the graph alone (right).
thanks